# Divide and partition at roughly equivalent intervals across slots in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I have an array of objects that looks as follows:

```
[
  [
    { product: 1, mass: 60 },
    { product: 3, mass: 30 },
    { product: 3, mass: 20 }
  ], [
    { product: 4, mass: 80 },
    { product: 5, mass: 40 }
  ]
]
```

I want to double the size of this array, freeing up another slot adjacent to each slot. I want to take from the previous slot, and distribute a roughly equal mass into this newly created slot. As an example, it would look as follows:

```
[
  [
    // total mass: 60
    { product: 1, mass: 60 },
  ], [
    // total mass: 50. Newly created.
    { product: 3, mass: 30 },
    { product: 3, mass: 20 }
  ], [
    // total mass: 80
    { product: 4, mass: 80 },
  ], [
    // total mass: 40. Newly created.
    { product: 5, mass: 40 }
  ]
]
```

How would this be done in JavaScript?

Comment: What have you done so far to try and do this?

Comment: this is an interesting question. before trying to implement it in javascript, try to think of how you would implement it manually, ie, if you were actually looking at a group of products on a shelf and you were going to do this task by hand

Comment: Does resulting order matter?

Comment: To an extent, it just must be in the adjacent well

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about resulting order the following code should work.

```
// helper function to get total mass
function total(arr) {
   return arr.reduce(function(total, item) { return total + item.mass;}, 0);
}

function distribute(cart) {
 // flatten products and sort
 var products = [].concat.apply([], cart)
     .sort(function(a, b){return b.mass - a.mass});
 // calc future avg mass
 var average = total(products)/(2*cart.length);

 return products.reduce(function(acc, product, index) {
   var last; 
   if(!index) { // the very first item
     acc.push([product]);
     return acc;
   }

  last = acc[acc.length - 1]; // take latest cart

  if(total(last) + product.mass > average) { // need next slot
      acc.push([product]);
  }
  else {
     last.push(product); // the last is still capable to get more items
  }
  return acc;
 }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a meh solution

```
export function distribute(
  group,
  field="mass",
  partitionCount=2,
  sorter=(a, b) => a[field] > b[field]
) {
  let index = 0;
  let partition = _.range(partitionCount).map(s => []);
  const copy = Array.from(group);
  while (copy.length !== 0) {
    const item = copy.sort(sorter).shift();
    partition[index%partition.length].push(item);
    index += 1;
  }
  return partition;
}

export function partitionByField(iterable, field="mass", partitionCount=2) {
  return Array.from(iterable).reduce((flattened, group) => {
    return flattened.concat(distribute(group, field, partitionCount));
  }, []);
}
```